# Call repository and service from controller layer with Spring

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, service, repository

I use Spring Boot and Spring Data.

I have no problem in my mind to separate Repository Layer and Service Layer

So I have my UserRepository with CRUD method and some Spring Data method

- findAll
- findByUsername

I also have UserService with business method.

- checkPassword(String login,String password)
- businessMethodAction(String username)

Here is my question:

In my controller I have to call method from UserService and sometime from UserRepository. For the moment, I inject both in my controller, and I call service or repository

```
@Inject
UserService userService;

@Inject
UserRepository userRepository;

@RequestMapping("{username}")
private void myMethod(@PathVariable String username){
    return userRepository.findOne(username);
}

@RequestMapping("{username}/doBusineesAction")
private void myMethod(@PathVariable String username){
    return userService.doLogicalThin(username);
}
```

I'm just asking because I confused to inject both and to call one or the other in the same class

On another side, this would mean to duplicate method in service layer like this

```
public User findOne(String username){
 return userRepository.findOne(username);
}
```

What's your opinion?

Comment: For information, JHipster call repository to read, and use service to write

Answer (score 23):

Controller layer shouldn't ever call repository directly. You should always use the service layer because the service layer encapsulates your business logic surrounding that call. Just because currently there *isn't* any business logic, doesn't mean that you should skip the layer entirely.

Comment: what if it is as simple as findById method? If we do end up adding business logic in future then it can be taken back to service layer but why enforce it going via service layer just because we think six months down we might have some business logic around it.

Comment: @samuel ok, but why is that? only because of how you structure your code or there are limitations?

Comment: Please note that this is an opinionated answer. Personally, I'd say YAGNI - only create service classes/methods when they're actually needed. Nobody needs another layer of useless boilerplate.

Comment: "Controller layer shouldn't ever call repository directly" What rule book did you get that from? The Uncle Bob one, or one of the hundreds of others we are supposed to follow blindly as if it were law?

Answer (score 4):

If your controller does not require business logic or perform a single repository operation, you can use the repositories directly. Use services to implement use cases that require business logic or orchestration of repository calls.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a layered CRUD app, I think it's fine for the controller to have knowledge of the repository and directly call it for simple read operations as long as the app is simple, small

Tradeoffs:

- The controller calling the repo removes the layer of abstraction of the service layer
- The controller and repository are now coupled
- If you don't have requirements/use cases/business logic for your read op., I would suggest not rolling out a full service. YAGNI (you aren't going to need it). Meaning, it doesn't make sense to implement an extra 'pass through' service layer at this time given the business needs.
- Before you choose to make your controller aware of your repository, I suggest to consider whether or not you've decoupled your repository layer from your persistence layer.

The structure of `controller -> service -> repository -> persistence` is not a hard and fast rule, as opposed to `controller -> repository -> persistence`. Your use case seems to fit the latter.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the service layer must implement the business logic and it must be called from controllers. In most of the cases, this layer has to perform more operations than just calling a method from a DAO object. This is probably the best solution if your application has great size. Also, you can split your logic into several parts and make it working in one transaction, that help you to save the data in the non-controversial state.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need transaction and no business logic is involved there is no need to have extra code that doesn't do anything.

There are examples in spring documentation when controller is calling repo.
Example 51 from here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#reference for example.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to reserve controllers are for business level concepts displayed on the views and repositories for the normalized entities in the DB. One can then define services to address the many-to-many relationship between controllers and repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should not be using both the service and repo class within the controller class. These are some good practices while using SpringBoot:

1. Repo class should be injected in Service class
2. Service class has to be injected in the Controller class

Following this you can use it efficiently. Using both the service and repo objects within controller is like confusing the spring context which instance to be called.

Answer (score -1):

The correct annotation is `@Autowired`, not `@Inject`, if you are using spring boot.

Comment: rather if you are use "spring" it seems there are so many confunsion abot "Spring" and "Spring boot"

Comment: Spring supports the JakartaEE @Inject annotation as well.